# iPhone: sticky on-screen header or footer in webkit (HTML/css)

Tags: iphone, html, css

Is it possible to create a sticky header or footer such that no matter where you scroll the header/footer stays put? I'm looking for a HTML/css/javascript solution for iPhone/webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: best resource I've found so far is this one: http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/

However, I think I'm going to end up using [Titanium from Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/) instead of just html/css.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to do this with JavaScript, as MobileSafari deliberately leaves out support for CSS's `position: fixed`. You should be able to detect the current viewport and absolutely position an element in the right spot, and update its location when the viewport changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another attempt to emulate position: fixed :

http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch/5

But it's hacky, and not very performant too.

You are right, Titanium or phonegap do the job well...