# Is sticky footer at bottom possible on iPad website?

Tags: css

Is sticky footer at bottom possible on iPad? I'm making a website which also need to be compatible on iPad and that site I need to use Sticky footer at Bottom.

Comment: @Blender - But it's touch screen

Comment: Whoops, wrong sticky footer. I was thinking of one which gets pushed around with the content. That I am not too sure about.

Comment: Maybe duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462808/iphone-sticky-on-screen-header-or-footer-in-webkit-html-css

Answer (score 4):

In case it's useful for someone else, this code solved it for me for Ipad IOS6 Safari and Chrome:

```
if (navigator.platform == 'iPad') {
    $("#footer-container").css("position", "static");
    $('#footer-container').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 10 + "px");
}
```

My situation was that on showing the keyboard my footer div got pushed into the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that position:fixed is not supported by the iPad, so you need javascript to do the trick, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

As of ios5 position:fixed is supported (partially)

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get it as close as possible. (it does jump, but it's better than nothing.

```
// IphoneIpad hack, to keep footer on bottom
        $(document).bind('scroll', function() {
            if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
                $('#footerContainer').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 30 + "px");
            }
        });
```